# teamcity windows agent not connecting to teamcity server running in Ubuntu

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-9.0

I am trying to connect teamcity server running in Ubuntu, from windows but its not working.

I changed firewall settings and opened up port 9090 and 8111.

I got these logs from windows agent

> Call http://my.domain.com:8111/RPC2 buildServer.registerAgent3:
>   org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcException:
>   jetbrains.buildServer.CannotPingAgentException: Unable to ping agent .
>   Check firewall and/or try to specify 'ownAddress' in the agent
>   configuration. Details: Agent '' cannot be accessed by any of the
>   addresses: [183.83.50.68, 192.168.1.146], (port 9090)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that TeamCity server can't access TeamCity agent by the specified addresses and port.

Ensure that your agent IP address is 183.83.50.68 and that incoming connections to the 9090 port are not blocked by not only firewall, but also by antivirus or similar software.

Or you can update to the TeamCity 9.1 or later - in these versions server doesn't have to be able to connect to the agent, only agent-to-server connection is necessary.

Comment: No, 9.1 works with java 1.6.
10.0 requires java 1.8, but for the server only, not for the agents